# Scratch Org: How to increase API Usage limit (i.e. allowed number of API requests per 24 hours)

Tags: salesforcedx, api, limits, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

Is there any way to increase API Usage limit in scratch org? I cannot find any setting to do so via json config file (we can increase number of custom objects, apex code size limit etc., but nothing re api usage limit).

Currently we can see 100,000 request being allowed per 24 hours period, right after scratch org creation. Even when using 'shape org' feature to sort of clone from prod org with higher API Usage limit, we sill cannot get more in scratch org than 100,000.

We were planning to move from sandbox to scratch org as our qa environment, but our qa guys usually put a lot of pressure on an org, so it needs to have higher api usage limit.

Are we missing something here? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000315571&type=1), API Request limit increase requests for Scratch Orgs are not supported and maximum allocated [DailyApiRequests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_editions_and_allocations.htm) is 100000.

You can temporary increase API limit for a maximum of two weeks for business orgs(non-scratch orgs) when business is impacted critically. For permanent increase you would need to coordinate with your Account Executive.

Answer (score 2):

That's one of the disadvantages of Scratch Orgs. That said, without knowing specifics, you may want to consider using Sandboxes with [Source Tracking](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_enable_source_tracking_sandboxes.htm). This gives you the push/pull feature while retaining the limits of your production org in most aspects. Also keep in mind that you can create 80-200 scratch orgs a day in production Dev Hub orgs, so you might also consider giving each QA person their own Scratch Org (or, you can have them each set up Dev Hub Developer Edition orgs to have even more orgs per day).